# Can the Lagrange Interpolating polynomial be used in a machine learning algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, lagrange-interpolation

My understanding of the **Lagrange interpolating polynomial** is that given $\space n \space$ points, we can fit a polynomial of degree $\space n+1 \space$ as a means of approximating the values between the points.

This polynomial is defined as:

$$L_n(x) = {(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_n) \over (x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)...(x_0-x_n)}y_0 +...+ {(x-x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_{n-1}) \over (x_n-x_1)(x_n-x_2)...(x_n-x_{n-1})}y_n$$

Could this be more reliable in a machine learning algorithm that deals with one numerical input and one numerical output, where the training data is a set of points $\space (x,y)  \space$, with $\space x=input \space$ and $\space y=output \space$ . Rather than using neural networks?

Comment: First, the Lagrange form is really bad to actually evaluate for $n$ larger than about $5$. There are better representations of the same polynomial, such as the Newton form, out there. Second, the big problem with exact interpolating polynomials of high degree (rather than, for example, inexact interpolating polynomials of low degree, or spline polynomials with low degree pieces) is large oscillations in between nodes. As a result you tend to get very inaccurate results for predictions of outputs from inputs in between the nodes.

Comment: @Ian - Ahh I figured your second point would be an issue but wasn't too sure. Thank you for the clear and concise response :)

Comment: Lagrange multiplier method IS restated in  SVM optimization problem - for Hard Margin Problems (as is lineary separability of data without outliers - important) - can read [here](https://shuzhanfan.github.io/2018/05/understanding-mathematics-behind-support-vector-machines/)... SVM also can provide Soft Margin solutions (if you make Regularization parameter C small) - for non-linearity

Comment: for huge data amount better use Spline (piece-wise) Interpolation (espesially Cubic Spline Interpolation)

Comment: one more Tip: fitting a univariate Local Linear Trend model using Kalman-filter is equivalent to Cubic Spline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with interpolation polynomials is that "they are trying too hard to fit the data points" and end up missing the structure of the dataset. This problem is called [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) and you should be aware of it. It happens when you use a larger than necerssary degree polynomial for regression.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding :). Been studying Neural Networks and having a look at Interpolating polynomials wondering why we don't just default to them. Just looked at overfitting, and the issue is clear. Thank you again.

Comment: You are very welcome!

Comment: @UndercoverCoder It isn't without merit, especially if the training data is known to be highly reliable.  Check out Polyharmonic Splines as a more widely applicable interpolation method.  The problem Ian talked about has a name as well, it is Runge's Phenomenon and is not quite the same as merely an issue with overfitting, but can be mitigated with constraints as well.  That is, even absent of Runge's phenomenon overfitting training data that isn't high confidence can be problematic.